# Functional/acceptance testing - multilanguage websites

Tags: testing, functional-testing, behat, acceptance-testing

Any best practices of creating acceptance and functional tests for multilingual sites? I would like to test content and functionality on multiple languages but not duplicate the tests.

If we take Behat, how to arrange a test environment from the very beginning?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Scenario Outlines: http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html#scenario-outlines

```
language | label1 | label2 |
es       | Hola   | Adios  | 
en       | Hello  | Bye    |
```